# localhost and IP for IIS express server

Tags: iis-express

I start a local IIS express server by command:

```
IISexpress.exe /path:C:\inetpub\mypath /port:8082
```

When I browse localhost:8082 it shows well. But if I browse start with IP: 10.x.x.x:8082, I got a "HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid."
Even though I had changed IIS express's applicationhost.config with

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":8082:10.x.x.x" />
```

and restarted, why?

Answer (score 0):

The command line (with /path) you used would ignore completely any config file. Please check Microsoft documentation for more details.

It is highly recommended that you do use /config instead of /path, as that exposes all settings to you.